# CLassical Mechanics | Relative velocity and Acceleration

Tags: classical-mechanics

With distances measured in **nm** and velocity measured in **knots**, 3 ships $A,B,C$ are observed from a coast guard station. At noon they have the following position and vectors relative to the station.

$\vec{r_A}=-\mathbf i+\mathbf j$ and $\vec{v_A}=\mathbf i+\mathbf j$

$\vec{r_B}=-3\mathbf i+4\mathbf j$ and $    \vec{v_B}=2\mathbf j$

$\vec{r_C}=9\mathbf i+4\mathbf j$ and $\vec{v_C}=-6\mathbf i+2\mathbf j$

Find the position vector of each ship after an hour.
Prove that if the ship continues with the same velocity, two of them will collide.
Find the time when this happens.

I've tried to understand the question, but I have not.

Comment: [Knot (unit)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_(unit)) "is a unit of speed equal to one nautical mile per hour."

Comment: Thus, it may help to draw a plot applying the speed vector to the initial position and compute what happens after an hour.

Comment: Consider e.g. ship A: initial position (with ref to the $(i,j)$ plane) point $(-1,1)$. Applying velocity vector $(1,1)$, after an hour we will find it in position $(0,2)$. And so on.

Comment: After 2 hours B and C will collide in point $(-3, 8)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA would you be kind to explain how I apply the vector velocity, and why we do Consider Ship A over the others.